# Making it beep in c++

Tags: c++

I've recently picked up C++ and I am using a Mac with Xcode to start learning.

One of the problems I am having is making it BEEP!!

I know there is a lot of StackOverflow questions for this and the most popular seems to be `std::cout << "\007"`

```
#include < iostream >

int main() {
    std::cout << "\007";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you certain that the console treats the beep character as a beep?

Comment: I am not sure, This is only my second day of learning c++

Comment: There's also [`system("say hi")`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).

Comment: OK yes!! This worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 3):

Try `cout << '\a' << flush;` instead. You can make a system call like `system("say beep");` but this is very OS dependent and will not work on all machines.

Comment: I just did, but the console only showed the number 1

Comment: Does this mean there is something wrong with my compiler?

Comment: No its your console.

Comment: Try to compile it in terminal instead of `Xcode` with `g++ -std=c++11 your_script.cpp -o script` and running it with `./script`

Comment: How would I go about solving my console problem?

Comment: See if you get a beep when you type it yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Comment: `std::cout << "\007" << std::flush` works for me, but if your terminal is not set to beep that might be suppressed. On macOS Terminal has a preference under "Advanced" for "Audible Bell" that might be turned off.

Comment: He suggested that he is using `Xcode` so he might be compiling and running on there too.